# alert when paypal redirects to the return page. php

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

```
switch($action)
{        
    case "process": // case process insert the form data in DB and process to the paypal

        $p->add_field('return', $return_url); // return URL after the transaction got over
}
```

when transaction got completed the above `$p->add_field` takes back the page to the return url path. I want to alert when this `$return_url` runs.

Comment: so u can put the alert on ur success page

Comment: yeah i did but that didn't diplayed anything. I even used exit; in the success case but i think its not going in the success